# Vim doesnt respect vimrc indentation settings

Tags: vim

I am new to using Vim, and have been using "The Ultimate Vim configuration" on GitHub. It uses 4 spaces wide tabs as default, so to change that, I changed my .vimrc file to the following:

```
set runtimepath+=~/.vim_runtime

source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/basic.vim
source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/filetypes.vim
source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/plugins_config.vim
source ~/.vim_runtime/vimrcs/extended.vim

" Own settings
set number
set tabstop=2
set softtabstop=2
set shiftwidth=2
set expandtab
set smarttab

try
source ~/.vim_runtime/my_configs.vim
catch
endtry
```

The my_configs.vim file is deleted, so I know that the indentation settings are not being overwritten there.

The problem is, if i source the vimrc file from vim with `:source ~/.vimrc` The indentation works perfectly, but if I close Vim and open again, then the indentation is back to 4 spaces wide instead of 2 as specified in the vimrc... All other settings from the Ultimate Vim Configuration get loaded from vimrc but not the indentation settings, which is really frustrating, as I need to source the vimrc file every time i want to use vim.

Any help is greatly appreciated, I really would like to exclusively use Vim but if this cannot be solved then I need to keep using Visual Studio Code :(

Thank you in advance.

EDIT: Here is the output of running command `:verbose set tabstop? softtabstop? shiftwidth?`:

```
tabstop=2, Last set from ~/.vimrc line 10
softtabstop=2, Last set from ~/.vimrc line 11
shiftwidth=2, Last set from ~/.vimrc line 12
```

Comment: Using someone else's `vimrc` is a very bad idea. You should consider scrapping it and learning Vim properly.

Comment: "*All other settings … get loaded from vimrc but not the indentation settings*" That, surely not possible and not the case. All settings are loaded but some are overridden later. See where: `:verbose set tabstop? softtabstop? shiftwidth?`

Comment: @phd The output of that command has been added, as you can see, theyre not getting overriden...

Comment: @Skosh All values are 2, when and where do you see 4?

Comment: what is the problem then? Does it add 4 Spaces? -> Have a look at the mappings of tab. Does it change space to tab? Does it change the number of spaces already there?

Comment: @DoktorOSwaldo Yes thats my problem EXACTLY. All values are 2, yet when i code for instance in python, it AUTOMATICALLY adds 4 spaces for indentation, if I press tab it also adds 4 spaces.

Comment: @phd That is my problem exactly, all values are 2, yet when i press tab or when my code gets autoindented, its indented with 4 spaces instead of 2...

Comment: have you called the `:verbose set tabstop? softtabstop? shiftwidth?` command in a python file? there are file types plugins. Do you have any plugins that are changing tab behaviour?

Comment: Consider using [Vi.se] for your questions on Vim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're editing a Python file in Vim, it will auto-detect the file type and apply Python specific settings. Amongst those, it will set the soft tab stop recommended by PEP 8.

You can find these settings in [`ftplugin/python.vim`](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/v8.2.0/runtime/ftplugin/python.vim#L118) in your Vim runtime:

```
if !exists("g:python_recommended_style") || g:python_recommended_style != 0
    " As suggested by PEP8.
    setlocal expandtab shiftwidth=4 softtabstop=4 tabstop=8
endif
```

You can override those settings with a global variable, which you can set in your vimrc. To disable the Python tab stop automatically set by Vim, include the following somewhere in your vimrc:

```
let g:python_recommended_style = 0
```

Note that those settings are there for a reason, they're pretty standard for Python and it's highly unusual to see Python code indented by a different number of spaces... But you have the knob to override it if you really want to.